# SaveChanges() does not work anywhere in the whole project. (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently working on a project, where the company wants me to migrate the whole project from Telerik to EF.

The old project used a lot of automatically generated code from Telerik, but now I can't use it anymore. So I decided to generate it using EF, so I used it, and I generated the whole EntitiesModel: [This is what I generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQIHN.png)

But I found out that SaveChanges() suddenly has stopped working: [Small part of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPJBg.png)

It have no definition.

I am getting this error message:
'EntitiesModel' does not contain a definition for 'SaveChanges', and no accessible extension method 'SaveChanges' accepting a first argument of type 'EntitiesModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't know how to fix this issue. Could you help me out, please?

EDIT:
I found out that the last fellow who was writing this code done this, I need to repair it. Would you recommend me please how should I do it? [Quickfixcode...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMAJj.png)

Comment: 2 things, put your code as code and not images please, but also *can you show the `GetDB` method plese?*

Comment: Is this entity framework 6 or entity framework core? How did you reverse engineer the database?

Answer (score 0):

SaveChanges() is an Entity Framework DbContext method. As far as I know, it does not exist on the type you're trying to use it on.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Supposing you've set up your project and entity framework correctly, if you want to delete any entry in your DB using EF, you'll first have to instanciate or inject AkroEntities DbContext and do something like the following :

```
var entity = akroEntitiesInstance.TFirmyLokalitas.FirstOrDefault(f => f.id == primaryKey)

if (entity != null)
{
    akroEntitiesInstance.TFirmyLokalitas.Delete(entity);
    akroEntitiesInstance.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the context or Entity of the project, you need to define it in the constructor and be able to access the desired tables.

Test the following code:

```
  private readonly AcroEntities _akroEntitiesInstance;
  public YourController(AcroEntities  akroEntitiesInstance)
  {
      _akroEntitiesInstance= akroEntitiesInstance;
  }

  public static void Delete(int key)
  {
   var Item = _akroEntitiesInstance.TFirmyLokalitas.FirstOrDefault(f => 
   f.id == key);

     if(Item != null)
     {
        _akroEntitiesInstance.TFirmyLokalitas.Delete(Item);
        _akroEntitiesInstance.SaveChanges();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in this app. I tried it and it wont work. I would need help, how to write generally Add(), Delete(), Savechanges() please.

Comment: What is the error message?